# Canvas : why is this color difference?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to draw a line on my canvas with color "#ca5100" but when my canvas is drawn the reel color is actually "#e4a77f" and not "#ca5100". Why is this difference ? and how to draw with the color you set.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("mycanva").getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle="#ca5100";
ctx.moveTo(0,50);
ctx.lineTo(500,50);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanva" width="500" height="100"></canvas>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My answer may be a duplicate but ill repost it, the solution is strange, instead of starting from (0,50) and move to (500,50) , you will need to start from (0,49.5) and move to (500,49.5)

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("mycanva").getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle="#ca5100";
ctx.moveTo(0,49.5);
ctx.lineTo(500,49.5);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanva" width="500" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: Could you explain why?